# Recepcion de un JSON en C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, jsonobject

Estoy tratando de recibir un archivo JSON en un controlador de C#, el envio lo hago desde una funcion de JavaScript, el problema radica en que si modifico el el tipo de variable en la funcion `CreateInfoInfor` no recibo ningun valor, la variable llega null o llega como un string que no logro deserializar, he intentado tambien solo enviar desde mi funcion `InforToReport()` un array, pero al realizar pruebas si dentro del array hay mas de 50 elementos, recibo en C# la variable de forma nula, si la envio formateada como `JSON.stringify()` no logro deserializarlo, este es el codigo que llevo de momento:
La función en C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateInfoInfor(JsonAttribute info_to_infor)
{
    List<InfoInfor> datainfor = new List<InfoInfor> { };
    List<InfoInfor> des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, InfoInfor>>(info_to_infor);
    try {
        if (info_to_infor != null)
        {
            // Ruta del archivo xlsx existente
            string originalFilePath = "wwwroot/media/Layout_Scrap.xlsx";
            string copyFilePath = "wwwroot/media/Layout_Scrap_Copy.xlsx";

            // Copiar el archivo original a un nuevo archivo
            System.IO.File.Copy(originalFilePath, copyFilePath, true);

            // Cargar el libro de trabajo (workbook) desde el nuevo archivo
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(copyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileStream);

                // Obtener la hoja 'data' del libro de trabajo
                ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("data");

                // Comenzar a insertar datos desde la celda D2
                int rowIndex = 1; // Fila 2

                foreach (var info in info_to_infor)
                {
                    // Crear una nueva fila en la hoja de cálculo
                    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(rowIndex) ?? sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);

                    // Reiniciar la columna a la posición D para cada fila
                    int columnIndex = 0; // Columna D

                    // Obtener las propiedades de la clase InfoInfor
                    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(InfoInfor).GetProperties();

                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                    {
                        // Obtener el valor de la propiedad
                        object value = property.GetValue(info);

                        // Convertir el valor a cadena antes de asignarlo a la celda
                        string cellValue = value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

                        // Crear una nueva celda y establecer su valor
                        ICell cell = row.GetCell(columnIndex) ?? row.CreateCell(columnIndex, CellType.String);
                        cell.SetCellValue(cellValue);

                        // Mover a la siguiente columna
                        columnIndex++;
                    }

                    // Mover a la siguiente fila
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                // Guardar los cambios de vuelta al archivo
                using (FileStream saveStream = new FileStream(copyFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    workbook.Write(saveStream);
                }
            }
            return Ok("Layout_Scrap_Copy.xlsx");
        }
        else { return BadRequest(); }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    } 
}
```

La función de JavaScript desde donde envio el JSON que necesito usar:

```
function InforToReport() {
    // Constants
    const serieValue = 10;
    const tipoOrdenValue = 'R70';
    const ordenValue = 'Fabricación JSC (manual)'
    let movi = 'Entrega'
    const companyValue = 2000;
    const r = 1;
    const almacenaje = 1;
    let lineaOrdenValue = 10;
    const rows = [];
    // Fill in the data
    report_json.forEach(entry => {
        if (!entry.numeroparte.includes('COVER')) //Solo agrega las partes que no son COVER
        {
            var row = {
                status: '', //Columna A
                code: '', //Columna B
                message: '', //Columna C
                compania: companyValue, //Columna D
                orden: ordenValue, //Columna E
                ordenf: '', //Columna F
                almacenaje: almacenaje, //Columna G
                movimiento: movi, //Columna H
                companiai: companyValue, //Columna I
                movimientoj: 'KTPFT', //Columna J
                companiak: companyValue, //Columna K
                almacenajel: 'W2P', //Columna L
                serie: serieValue, //Columna M
                torde: tipoOrdenValue, //Columna N
                depto: 'W2P', //Columna O
                companiap: companyValue, //Columna P
                lorden: lineaOrdenValue, //Columna Q
                r: r, //Columna R
                articulo: '', //Columna S
                nummeroparte: agregarEspaciosEnNumeroParte(entry.numeroparte), //Columna T
                cantidad: entry.cantidad, //Columna U
                v: 'pc', //Columna V
                reasonscrap: retornaTipoScrap(entry.tipo) //Columna W
            };
            rows.push(row);

            // Increment Linea de orden for the next entry
            lineaOrdenValue += 10;
        }
    });
    console.log(rows);
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(rows);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Reportes/CreateInfoInfor",
        traditional: 'true',
        data: { 'info_to_infor': jsonData },
        success: function (fileName) {
            alertify.success('Infor File OK'); 
            // Construir la URL de descarga
            var downloadUrl = "../media/" + fileName;
            console.log(fileName);

            // Crear un enlace temporal y hacer clic en él para iniciar la descarga
            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
            downloadLink.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alertify.error('Algo salio mal!'); 
        }
    });
}
```

Y la clase con la que he intentando deserializar el JSON que estoy enviando:

```
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Keyless]
    public class InfoInfor
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string? Status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string? Code { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string? Message { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("compania")]
        public int? Compania { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("orden")]
        public string? Orden { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ordenf")]
        public string? Ordenf { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("almacenaje")]
        public string? Almacenaje { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("movimiento")]
        public string? Movimiento { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("companiai")]
        public int? Companiai { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("movimientoj")]
        public string? Movimientoj { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("companiak")]
        public int? Companiak { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("almacenajel")]
        public string? Almacenajel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("serie")]
        public int? Serie { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("torde")]
        public string? Torde { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("depto")]
        public string? Depto { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("companiap")]
        public int? Companiap { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("lorden")]
        public int? Lorden { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("r")]
        public int? R { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("articulo")]
        public string? Articulo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("nummeroparte")]
        public string? Nummeroparte { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("cantidad")]
        public int? Cantidad { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("v")]
        public string? V { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("reasonscrap")]
        public string? Reasonscrap { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre la deserialización del objeto, con los siguientes cambios, para el controlador

```
public IActionResult CreateInfoInfor(String info_to_infor)
{
List<InfoInfor> infoToInforDeserializer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InfoInfor>>(info_to_infor);
 //Resto de codigo
}
```

Todo lo demas quedo igual.